# Deep Insert on Business Partner via SAP Cloud SDK VDM doesn't work on to_Customer

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to create a business partner including a customer, a customer sales area and a customer company with the SAP Cloud SDK.

This is how I create my business partner vdm:

```java
 final CustomerSalesArea customerSalesArea = CustomerSalesArea.builder()
                .salesOrganization("YOD1")
                .distributionChannel("Y2")
                .division("Z1")
                .currency("EUR")
                .customerAccountAssignmentGroup("01")
                .customerPaymentTerms("0001")
                .customerPricingProcedure("Y1")
                .incotermsClassification("FH")
                .itemOrderProbabilityInPercent("100")
                .orderCombinationIsAllowed(true)
                .customerAccountGroup("CUST")
                .build();

        final CustomerCompany company = CustomerCompany.builder()
                .companyCode("YOD1")
                .reconciliationAccount("0012100000")
                .customerAccountGroup("CUST")
                .build();

        final Customer customer = Customer.builder()
                .customerSalesArea(customerSalesArea)
                .customerCompany(company)
                .build();

        final BusinessPartner businessPartner = BusinessPartner.builder()
                .firstName(oxidBusinessPartner.getFirstName())
                .middleName(oxidBusinessPartner.getMiddleName())
                .lastName(oxidBusinessPartner.getLastName())
                .businessPartnerCategory("1")
                .correspondenceLanguage("DE")
                .businessPartnerIDByExtSystem(oxidBusinessPartner.getCustomerId())
                .customer(customer)
                .build();

        final BusinessPartnerRole businessPartnerRole1 = BusinessPartnerRole.builder()
                .businessPartnerRole("FLCU00")
                .build();

        final BusinessPartnerRole businessPartnerRole2 = BusinessPartnerRole.builder()
                .businessPartnerRole("FLCU01")
                .build();

        businessPartner.addBusinessPartnerRole(businessPartnerRole1);
        businessPartner.addBusinessPartnerRole(businessPartnerRole2);

        final AddressEmailAddress emailAddress = AddressEmailAddress.builder()
                .emailAddress(oxidBusinessPartner.getEmail())
                .build();

        for (PostalAddress address : oxidBusinessPartner.getPostalAddresses()) {
            final BusinessPartnerAddress businessPartnerAddress = BusinessPartnerAddress.builder()
                    .country(address.getCountry())
                    .cityName(address.getCity())
                    .postalCode(address.getZipCode())
                    .county(address.getRegion())
                    .emailAddress(emailAddress)
                    .build();

            businessPartner.addBusinessPartnerAddress(businessPartnerAddress);
        }
```

Now, I am able to successfully create this business partner with the `DefaultBusinessPartnerService`. However the actual deep insert doesn't seem to work properly as the `Customer` is not created.

I can confirm this by querying the `A_BusinessPartner` API with an expand to `to_Customer`, which returns `null`. The deep insert on the `BusinessPartnerRole` however worked as expected.

So, what am I missing here? Is there some sort of dependency, such as that I first need to create a `BusinessPartner` and then a `Customer` (I am by no means an expert in S4/HANA)? But then again, the SAP Cloud SDK doesn't provide a method to create a `Customer` and neither does api.sap.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I leave the customer "empty", so if I just do 
`Customer customer = Customer.builder().build();` and attach it to the Business Partner, the Customer entity is somehow created. I then use the OData Servives /A_CustomerCompany and /A_CustomerSalesArea to create those entities respectively and everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to create instances of *Customer* entity when using the *Business Partner API*. In the [official documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4f4961c3dc914a3f92865c74add17c9d/1908.500/en-US/85043858ea0f9244e10000000a4450e5.html#d4h5-main-content) you will find only support for "Reading" and "Updating" Customers. I looked for an alternative Rest service in the *SAP API Business Hub* and found the [Customer Master service](https://api.sap.com/api/SAP_CF_EMS_Customer_Master/resource), with limited functionality though. Maybe it allows the creation of Customers.

Comment: Hey Alexander, thank you for your reply. I think I found another work around: If I leave the customer "empty", so if I just do `Customer customer = Customer.builder().build();` and attach it to the Business Partner, the Customer entity is somehow created. I then use the OData Servives `/A_CustomerCompany` and `/A_CustomerSalesArea` to create those entities respectively and everything works as expected.

Comment: Interesting! Great find. I was not aware of this implicit behavior of _BusinessPartnerService_. I think you can add your response as a dedicated _answer_ and mark your question as resolved.